# Mouse-over event p-dataTable table cell

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm using `text-overflow:ellipsis` for my cells to keep rows' height consistent and I want to be able to show full content using mouseover in `p-dataTable` PrimeNG.

Comment: Please show a minimal, verifiable and complete example, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [templating](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/templating) for your cells.

```
<p-column field="color" header="Color">
    <ng-template let-col let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <span title="{{data[col.field]}}">{{data[col.field]}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

and use the [Primeng tooltip](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tooltip) component or just a title attribute on the span.